# Arrays.copyTo() from Java in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

There is a function in Java "Arrays.copyTo()" and I need to find a method that works the same way as Arrays.copyTo() in C#. How would I do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0

Comment: [`Array.CopyTo` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copyto?view=net-5.0)

Comment: It is generally frowned upon asking questions without trying to find an answer first. Please indicate what research you've done to find an answer before posting a question here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it demonstrates a complete lack of research.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] arr = new string[n];
string[] newArray = new string[m];
Array.Copy(arr, newArray , length);
```

So this is for C#

**Array.Copy** has four different overloads

Answer (score 0):

There are two examples of this on Microsoft's own site. [Array.Copy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copyto?view=net-5.0)[Array.Copy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0) or [Array.Copy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0)

for example
you first create two new array

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var source = new[] { "Ally", "Bishop", "Billy" };
        var target = new string[4];
        
        target.SetValue("onur",0);
        target.SetValue("veli",1);
        target.SetValue("deli",2);
        source.CopyTo(target, 1);
        foreach (var item in target)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    
    }
}
```

or

```
var source = new[] { "Ally", "Bishop", "Billy" };
var target = new[] { "Veli", "Deli", "lly", "Kel" };

Array.Copy(source, target,1);
foreach (var item in target)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```